# Registration form does not trigger registration method

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, spring-webflux

When submitting the form, the parameters mapped inside the Model should be passed to the `RegistrationController.java` and then to the `register()` metheod, where they would be mapped to the `RegistrationRequest`-Object. But actually none of that is happening. It leads me to nothing. No errors in the debugger. Not even a status code is emitted.

Only my custom errorhandler says:

```
{"timestamp":"31-10-2021 19:40:12", "error":"null", "status":-1, "path": "null"}
```

-1 is when no status code can be derived.
But this is probably because I didn't set any redirection after submitting.
The POST Status seems to be `200 OK`.

## Edit

*I added the class containing the `registrationService.reg()`.*

**registration.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Please Register</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #3e3e3e;
            color: white;

        } 
    </style>
    
</head>
  <body>
    <!-- Create HTML registration form -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                <!-- success message -->
                <div th:if="${param.success}">
                    <div class="alert alert-info">You've successfully registered</div>
                </div>

                <h1>Registration</h1>

                <form th:action="@{/registration/register}" th:object ="${user}" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
                        <input id="username" class="form-control" th:field="*{username}" required autofocus="autofocus" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label> 
                         <input id="email" class="form-control" th:field="*{email}" required autofocus="autofocus"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label> 
                        <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" th:field="*{password}" required autofocus="autofocus" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="matchingpassword">Confirm Password</label> 
                        <input id="matchingpassword" class="form-control" type="password" th:field="*{matchingpassword}" required autofocus="autofocus" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                        <span>Already registered? <a href="/" th:href="@{/login}">Login here</a></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**HomeController.java**

```
@RequestMapping
@Controller
public class HomeController {

...
    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public Mono<String> showRegistrationForm(final Model model) { 
    RegistrationRequest registrationRequest = new RegistrationRequest();
    model.addAttribute("user", registrationRequest);
    return Mono.just("registration");
}
   
}
```

**RegistrationRequest.java**

```
//@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@ValidEmail
public class RegistrationRequest {

    @NotNull(message = "Username can't be empty")
    @NotEmpty
    private String username;
 
    @NotNull(message = "Email can't be empty")
    @NotEmpty
    private String email;

    @NotNull(message = "Please choose a password")
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    @NotNull(message = "Please confirm password")
    @NotEmpty
    private String matchingpassword;

    
    private UserRole user_role;
 
    
    //Getter
    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

    public String getMatchingpassword(){
        return matchingpassword;
    }


    //Setter
    public String setUsername(final String username){
        return this.username = username;
    }

    public String setEmail(final String email){
        return this.email = email;
    }

    public String setPassword(final String password){
        return this.password = password;
    }

    public String setMatchingpassword(final String matchingpassword){
        return this.matchingpassword = matchingpassword;
    }
}
```

**RegistrationController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/registration")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationController {

    @Autowired 
    private RegistrationService registrationService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public Mono<String> register(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid RegistrationRequest user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("binding result has errors");
            return Mono.just("registration");
        }

        return registrationService.reg(user);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "confirm")
    public Mono<String> confirm(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
        return registrationService.confirmToken(token);
    }
    
}
```

**RegistrationService.java**

```
@Data
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationService {

    @Autowired
    private ConfirmationToken confirmationToken;
    private ConfirmationTokenService confirmationTokenService;
    private ApplicationUserService applicationUserService;
  
    public Mono<String> reg(RegistrationRequest request) {

        Mono<String> token = applicationUserService.signUpUser(
            new ApplicationUser(
                request.getUsername(),
                request.getPassword(),
                request.getEmail(),             
                UserRole.ROLE_USER     
             )
        );

        String link = "http://localhost:8081/registration/confirm?token=" + token;
buildEmail(request.getUsername(), link));

        return token;

    }
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    private final ApplicationUserService applicationUserService;
       
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http){
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/", "/login", "/Output", "/css/*", "/registration", "/register", "/registration/register", "/js/*").permitAll()       
            .pathMatchers("/input", "/login", "/logout", "/css/*").hasRole("USER") 
            .anyExchange()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .authenticationSuccessHandler(new RedirectServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/input"))
            .and()
            .logout()
                //.logoutUrl("/logout")
                .requiresLogout(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/logout"));
           
        return http.build();

    }


    @Bean
    ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager(ApplicationUserService applicationUserService){
        return new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(applicationUserService);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried from Postman and getting the proper response?

Comment: @ArunSai Yes. Postman gives me the result I mentioned in my quastion. Header `200 OK`. But body is `error:null, status:-1,path:null`. I can make it work without thymeleaf by just sending a `@BodyRequest` via postman. But I prefer thymeleaf.

Comment: What does `registrationService.reg(user)` used in the `register` method of `RegistrationController` return?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe In this case it returns nothing because it's not beeing invoked. But in a working case, without thymeleaf, it creates an `ApplicationUser`-Object containing all parameters from the `RegistrationRequest`-Object, which then is saved into the Database.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I've added the code from `RegistrationService`.